# Django displays wrong user account

Tags: python, django, postgresql, session, heroku

We're running a Django 1.9 app with around 200K users on Heroku. We normally see around 300 to 1000 active users any given time.

Today we received a complaint from one of our users that when she logged in, using her credentials, she was in another user's account. She logged out and tried again, only to see another user this time. We received the same complaint from another user a couple of months ago but we could not reproduce the issue. We're still unable to reproduce it. However it's even  more critica, as we're storing sensitive PII now.

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'simple_history.middleware.HistoryRequestMiddleware',
'pipeline.middleware.MinifyHTMLMiddleware'
]

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.sitemaps',
'django.contrib.humanize',
.
.
.
]
```

We're using Heroku's PostgreSQL DB as the session storage.

Any ideas what we might be doing wrong?

Comment: Really sounds like a caching issue

Comment: @mindcruzer I know but there's no caching involved.